# Material icons not rendering properly in chrome due to font extension

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

It seems to be that one of the Kannada fonts installed through chrome web store is causing the material icons to break. I have installed https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kannada-font-pack/ejfflcimohddeegmgkacpimbecmmjhon. Enabling the font causes rendering issues with material icons. Any suggestions welcome.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's understandable you don't want to loose what you have in your usual profile but it's also obvious that the profile has issues and this has nothing to do with Ubuntu so, why are you asking here?

Comment: try https://webapps.stackexchange.com maybe

Comment: Icons are not rendering properly in Chrome looks like a fair question for Ask Ubuntu to me.